# Run sql script files from inside of setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, setup-project

I need to build an add-on using Setup Project in VS 2010. The setup file should run sql script files that are inside of Setup project and copy/replace necessary assemblies into desired folder.
What is the best approach to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option would be to implement a Custom Action on the installer and then do whatever you need to from there. You can embed the script files in the installer package by setting their type as "Embedded Resource" in the project. Maybe have a look at this page from the MSDN library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx